# Is it correct to interpolate homogenous 4D coordinates?

Tags: opengl, glsl, interpolation

I would like to do something like this

```c
void main()
{
    vec4 prevPos = u_prevModelViewProj * a_pos;
    vec4 nextPos = u_nextModelViewProj * a_pos;
    gl_Position = mix(prevPos, nextPos, 0.5);
}
```

but I don't know if this kind of interpolation with 4D homogeneous coordinates is correct.

EDIT:

I just noticed that, since the projection matrix doesn't change in my particular case, I could do it like this:

```c
void main()
{
    vec3 nextPos = (u_nextModelView * a_pos).xyz;
    vec3 prevPos = (u_prevModelView * a_pos).xyz;
    gl_Position = u_proj * vec4(mix(prevPos, nextPos, 0.5), 1);
}
```

But I'm still curious for the original question

Answer (score 2):

I figured it's valid to do the interpolation. At least if the projection matrix doesn't change. Because matrix multiplication is both distributive and associative.

```
P * 0.5 * (M1 * x + M2 * x) = 
0.5 * (P*M1 * x + P*M2 * x)
```

EDIT:

**Perspective matrices with different FOVs**

I found another proof for a use case of [perspective matrices](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/120355/25615): the case of two perspective projection matrices with different FOVs (the other params, aspectRatio, nearPlane and farPlane are constant). It turned out that doing the interpolation with these conditions is also correct.

Here's the proof:

```
Let's define the "proj" operation as a projection from 4D homogeneous coords to 3D
    proj(a) = (a.x, a.y, a.z, a.w) / a.w

Given these two perspective projection matrices with different FOVs:

F1 = tan(0.5*fov1)
F2 = tan(0.5*fov2)
Ar: = aspect ratio
n: near plane
f: far plane

P1 = {
    1/(Ar*F1)   0       0             0
    0           1/F1    0             0
    0           0       (f+n)/(n-f)   2*n*f/(n-f)
    0           0       -1            0
}

P2 = {
    1/(Ar*F2)   0       0             0
    0           1/F2    0             0
    0           0       (f+n)/(n-f)   2*n*f/(n-f)
    0           0       -1            0
}

We hypothesize that we can do the interpolation before or after dividing by the W coordinate
So these two should be equivalent:
    proj(0.5*(P1*v + P2*v)) = 0.5*(proj(P1*a) + proj(P2*b))

P1 * v = {
    v.x/(Ar*F1),
    v.y/F1,
    v.z*(f+n)/(n-f) -v.w,
    v.z*2*n*f/(n-f)
}

P2 * v = {
    v.x/(Ar*F2),
    v.y/F2,
    v.z*(f+n)/(n-f) -v.w,
    v.z*2*n*f/(n-f)
}

proj(P1 * v) = {
    (v.x*(n-f))/(Ar*F1*v.z*2*n*f),
    (v.y*(n-f))/(F1*v.z*2*n*f),
    (v.z*(f+n) -v.w*(n-f)) / (v.z*2*n*f),
    1
}

proj(P2 * v) = {
    (v.x*(n-f))/(Ar*F2*v.z*2*n*f),
    (v.y*(n-f))/(F2*v.z*2*n*f),
    (v.z*(f+n) -v.w*(n-f)) / (v.z*2*n*f),
    1
}

// Result 1:
0.5 * (proj(P1 * v) + proj(P2 * v)) = {
    0.5 * (1/F1 + 1/F2) * v.x*(n-f)/(Ar*v.z*2*n*f),
    0.5 * (1/F1 + 1/F2) * v.y*(n-f)/(v.z*2*n*f),
    (v.z*(f+n) -v.w*(n-f)) / (v.z*2*n*f),
    1
}

P1 * v + P2 * v = { // note: we don't need to multiply by 0.5 to do the interpolation because we are about to do the "proj" anyways
    (1/F1 + 1/F2) * v.x/Ar,
    (1/F1 + 1/F2) * v.y,
    2*(v.z*(f+n)/(n-f) -v.w),
    2*v.z*2*n*f/(n-f)
}

// Result 2:
proj(P1 * v + P2 * v) = {
    0.5 * (1/F1 + 1/F2) * v.x*(n-f)/(Ar*v.z*2*n*f),
    0.5 * (1/F1 + 1/F2) * v.y*(n-f)/(v.z*2*n*f),
    (v.z*(f+n) -v.w*(n-f)) / (v.z*2*n*f),
    1
}

Results 1 and 2 are the same. So the hypothesis is correct.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you use the interpolation for positions it should be fine (as long as the projection matrix stays the same, else you could get some weird results, depending on how you change the projection matrix, because of the w axis) since you are interpolating position coordinates in the clip space, which is explicitly allowed.

Comment: "since you are interpolating position coordinated in the clip space, which is explicitly allowed" -> what do you mean by "allowed"?.
"else you could get some weird results" -> any proof for that?

Comment: "since you are interpolating position coordinates in the clip space, which is explicitly allowed" 
The Clip space contains the unscaled i.e. homogeneous device coordinates. Interpolating homogenous coordinates yields semantically right results.
The w-axis is the "Scaling factor" for the perspective transformation. For most use cases it should still yield correct results if the prev and next proj. Matrix differ, but changing one of those from a e.g. perspective to a orthographic projection, COULD yield weird results.

Comment: depends on your projection matrices and use cases

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Indeed interpolating the resulting vectors is equivalent to interpolating the matrices and transforming the input vector with that. Whether that does something reasonable depends on the structure of the matrix.

Scaling and translation interpolate in a reasonable way. Rotation and projection in general do not, but results stay reasonable if the matrixes that are interpolated between are *close enough*.

Below is an example of a rotating cube that receives two different model matrices, one normal one and one with extra angles added (based on the slider), the coordinates are transformed with both of them and then interpolated with `mix(v1, v2, 0.5)`. For *small angles* the distortion is not too bad, but it quickly gets out of hand and the cube can even completely disappear.

```js
var MDN = {};

  MDN.multiplyPoint = function (matrix, point) {
  
    var x = point[0], y = point[1], z = point[2], w = point[3];
  
    var c1r1 = matrix[ 0], c2r1 = matrix[ 1], c3r1 = matrix[ 2], c4r1 = matrix[ 3],
        c1r2 = matrix[ 4], c2r2 = matrix[ 5], c3r2 = matrix[ 6], c4r2 = matrix[ 7],
        c1r3 = matrix[ 8], c2r3 = matrix[ 9], c3r3 = matrix[10], c4r3 = matrix[11],
        c1r4 = matrix[12], c2r4 = matrix[13], c3r4 = matrix[14], c4r4 = matrix[15];
  
    return [
      x*c1r1 + y*c1r2 + z*c1r3 + w*c1r4,
      x*c2r1 + y*c2r2 + z*c2r3 + w*c2r4,
      x*c3r1 + y*c3r2 + z*c3r3 + w*c3r4,
      x*c4r1 + y*c4r2 + z*c4r3 + w*c4r4
    ];
  }

  MDN.multiplyMatrices = function (a, b) {
  
    // TODO - Simplify for explanation
    // currently taken from https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix/blob/master/src/gl-matrix/mat4.js#L306-L337
  
    var result = [];
  
    var a00 = a[0], a01 = a[1], a02 = a[2], a03 = a[3],
        a10 = a[4], a11 = a[5], a12 = a[6], a13 = a[7],
        a20 = a[8], a21 = a[9], a22 = a[10], a23 = a[11],
        a30 = a[12], a31 = a[13], a32 = a[14], a33 = a[15];

    // Cache only the current line of the second matrix
    var b0  = b[0], b1 = b[1], b2 = b[2], b3 = b[3];  
    result[0] = b0*a00 + b1*a10 + b2*a20 + b3*a30;
    result[1] = b0*a01 + b1*a11 + b2*a21 + b3*a31;
    result[2] = b0*a02 + b1*a12 + b2*a22 + b3*a32;
    result[3] = b0*a03 + b1*a13 + b2*a23 + b3*a33;

    b0 = b[4]; b1 = b[5]; b2 = b[6]; b3 = b[7];
    result[4] = b0*a00 + b1*a10 + b2*a20 + b3*a30;
    result[5] = b0*a01 + b1*a11 + b2*a21 + b3*a31;
    result[6] = b0*a02 + b1*a12 + b2*a22 + b3*a32;
    result[7] = b0*a03 + b1*a13 + b2*a23 + b3*a33;

    b0 = b[8]; b1 = b[9]; b2 = b[10]; b3 = b[11];
    result[8] = b0*a00 + b1*a10 + b2*a20 + b3*a30;
    result[9] = b0*a01 + b1*a11 + b2*a21 + b3*a31;
    result[10] = b0*a02 + b1*a12 + b2*a22 + b3*a32;
    result[11] = b0*a03 + b1*a13 + b2*a23 + b3*a33;

    b0 = b[12]; b1 = b[13]; b2 = b[14]; b3 = b[15];
    result[12] = b0*a00 + b1*a10 + b2*a20 + b3*a30;
    result[13] = b0*a01 + b1*a11 + b2*a21 + b3*a31;
    result[14] = b0*a02 + b1*a12 + b2*a22 + b3*a32;
    result[15] = b0*a03 + b1*a13 + b2*a23 + b3*a33;

    return result;
  }

  MDN.multiplyArrayOfMatrices = function (matrices) {
  
    var inputMatrix = matrices[0];
  
    for(var i=1; i < matrices.length; i++) {
      inputMatrix = MDN.multiplyMatrices(inputMatrix, matrices[i]);
    }
  
    return inputMatrix;
  }

  MDN.rotateXMatrix = function (a) {
  
    var cos = Math.cos;
    var sin = Math.sin;
  
    return [
         1,       0,        0,     0,
         0,  cos(a),  -sin(a),     0,
         0,  sin(a),   cos(a),     0,
         0,       0,        0,     1
    ];
  }

  MDN.rotateYMatrix = function (a) {

    var cos = Math.cos;
    var sin = Math.sin;
  
    return [
       cos(a),   0, sin(a),   0,
            0,   1,      0,   0,
      -sin(a),   0, cos(a),   0,
            0,   0,      0,   1
    ];
  }

  MDN.rotateZMatrix = function (a) {

    var cos = Math.cos;
    var sin = Math.sin;
  
    return [
      cos(a), -sin(a),    0,    0,
      sin(a),  cos(a),    0,    0,
           0,       0,    1,    0,
           0,       0,    0,    1
    ];
  }

  MDN.translateMatrix = function (x, y, z) {
    return [
        1,    0,    0,   0,
        0,    1,    0,   0,
        0,    0,    1,   0,
        x,    y,    z,   1
    ];
  }

  MDN.scaleMatrix = function (w, h, d) {
    return [
        w,    0,    0,   0,
        0,    h,    0,   0,
        0,    0,    d,   0,
        0,    0,    0,   1
    ];
  }

  MDN.perspectiveMatrix = function (fieldOfViewInRadians, aspectRatio, near, far) {
  
    // Construct a perspective matrix
  
    /*
       Field of view - the angle in radians of what's in view along the Y axis
       Aspect Ratio - the ratio of the canvas, typically canvas.width / canvas.height
       Near - Anything before this point in the Z direction gets clipped (outside of the clip space)
       Far - Anything after this point in the Z direction gets clipped (outside of the clip space)
    */
  
    var f = 1.0 / Math.tan(fieldOfViewInRadians / 2);
    var rangeInv = 1 / (near - far);
 
    return [
      f / aspectRatio, 0,                          0,   0,
      0,               f,                          0,   0,
      0,               0,    (near + far) * rangeInv,  -1,
      0,               0,  near * far * rangeInv * 2,   0
    ];
  }

function initShaderProgram(gl, vsSource, fsSource) {
  const vertexShader = loadShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vsSource);
  const fragmentShader = loadShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fsSource);

  // Create the shader program

  const shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

  // If creating the shader program failed, alert

  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    alert('Unable to initialize the shader program: ' + gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
    return null;
  }

  return shaderProgram;
}

function loadShader(gl, type, source) {
  const shader = gl.createShader(type);

  // Send the source to the shader object

  gl.shaderSource(shader, source);

  // Compile the shader program

  gl.compileShader(shader);

  // See if it compiled successfully

  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    alert('An error occurred compiling the shaders: ' + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
    gl.deleteShader(shader);
    return null;
  }

  return shader;
}

function createCubeData() {
  
    var positions = [
      // Front face
      -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
       1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
       1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
      -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,

      // Back face
      -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
      -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
       1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
       1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

      // Top face
      -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
      -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
       1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
       1.0,  1.0, -1.0,

      // Bottom face
      -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
       1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
       1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
      -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

      // Right face
       1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
       1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
       1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
       1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

      // Left face
      -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
      -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
      -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
      -1.0,  1.0, -1.0
    ];
  
    var colorsOfFaces = [
      [0.3,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0],    // Front face: cyan
      [1.0,  0.3,  0.3,  1.0],    // Back face: red
      [0.3,  1.0,  0.3,  1.0],    // Top face: green
      [0.3,  0.3,  1.0,  1.0],    // Bottom face: blue
      [1.0,  1.0,  0.3,  1.0],    // Right face: yellow
      [1.0,  0.3,  1.0,  1.0]     // Left face: purple
    ];
  
    var colors = [];

    for (var j=0; j<6; j++) {
      var polygonColor = colorsOfFaces[j];
    
      for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
        colors = colors.concat( polygonColor );
      }
    }
  
    var elements = [
      0,  1,  2,      0,  2,  3,    // front
      4,  5,  6,      4,  6,  7,    // back
      8,  9,  10,     8,  10, 11,   // top
      12, 13, 14,     12, 14, 15,   // bottom
      16, 17, 18,     16, 18, 19,   // right
      20, 21, 22,     20, 22, 23    // left
    ]
  
    return {
      positions: positions,
      elements: elements,
      colors: colors
    }
  }

createBuffersForCube = function( gl, cube ) {
  
    var positions = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positions);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(cube.positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  
    var colors = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colors);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(cube.colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  
    var elements = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elements);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(cube.elements), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  
    return {
      positions: positions,
      colors: colors,
      elements: elements
    }
  }

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas3d');
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl') || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");;

var vshader = `
  attribute vec3 position;
  attribute vec4 color;
  uniform mat4 model;
  uniform mat4 projection;
  uniform mat4 model2;
  varying vec4 vColor;
  void main() {
    vColor = color;
    vec4 v1 = projection * model * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    vec4 v2 = projection * model2 * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    gl_Position = mix(v1, v2, 0.5);
  }`;
var fshader = `
  precision mediump float;
  varying vec4 vColor;
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vColor;
  }`;

var program = initShaderProgram(gl, vshader, fshader);

const programInfo = {
  program: program,
  attributeLocations: {
    vpos: gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'position'),
    vcol: gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'color'),
  },
  uniformLocations: {
    proj: gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'projection'),
    model: gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'model'),
    model2: gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'model2'),
  },
};

var transforms = {};

var cube = createCubeData();
var buffers = createBuffersForCube(gl, cube);

computeModelMatrix = function( now ) {
  var scale = MDN.scaleMatrix(7, 7, 7);
  var rotateX = MDN.rotateXMatrix( now * 0.0003 );
  var rotateY = MDN.rotateYMatrix( now * 0.0005 );
  var position = MDN.translateMatrix(0, 0, -20);

  transforms.model = MDN.multiplyArrayOfMatrices([
    position, // step 4
    rotateY,  // step 3
    rotateX,  // step 2
    scale     // step 1
  ]);
  
  var angle = document.getElementById("angle").value * 0.0174533;
  rotateX = MDN.rotateXMatrix( now * 0.0003 + angle);
  rotateY = MDN.rotateYMatrix( now * 0.0005 + angle);
  
  transforms.model2 = MDN.multiplyArrayOfMatrices([
    position, // step 4
    rotateY,  // step 3
    rotateX,  // step 2
    scale     // step 1
  ]);
};

computePerspectiveMatrix = function() {
  
  var fieldOfViewInRadians = Math.PI * 0.5;
  var aspectRatio = 1;
  var nearClippingPlaneDistance = 1;
  var farClippingPlaneDistance = 50;
  
  this.transforms.projection = MDN.perspectiveMatrix(
    fieldOfViewInRadians,
    aspectRatio,
    nearClippingPlaneDistance,
    farClippingPlaneDistance
  );
};

updateAttributesAndUniforms = function() {
  
  // Setup the color uniform that will be shared across all triangles
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(programInfo.uniformLocations.model, false, new Float32Array(transforms.model));
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(programInfo.uniformLocations.model2, false, new Float32Array(transforms.model2));
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(programInfo.uniformLocations.proj, false, new Float32Array(transforms.projection));
  
  // Set the positions attribute
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(programInfo.attributeLocations.vpos);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.positions);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(programInfo.attributeLocations.vpos, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  
  // Set the colors attribute
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(programInfo.attributeLocations.vcol);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.colors);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(programInfo.attributeLocations.vcol, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.elements );
  
};

draw = function() {
  var now = Date.now();
  
  gl.useProgram(program);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  
  // Compute our matrices
  computeModelMatrix( now );
  computePerspectiveMatrix( 0.5 );
  
  // Update the data going to the GPU
  updateAttributesAndUniforms();
  
  // Perform the actual draw
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 36, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  
  
  // Run the draw as a loop
  requestAnimationFrame( draw );
};

draw();
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="360" value="20" class="slider" id="angle">
</div>
<canvas id="canvas3d" height="300" width="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks! this is not exactly what I was asking but is an interesting experiment +1